# JQuery - untoggle - removeClass is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple page with buttons. After clicking on the button, the text appears right under this button using `toggle`.

This work's correct but it does not "untoggle" another sections/buttons. So what I want is on click not just toggle the section under the button but also untoggle another toggled section.

I've added a loop over all sections which is executed right after click and it should "hide" all sections and then do what it has to do - show `this` section.

> ncaught TypeError: acc.removeClass is not a function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var accs = $('.accordion');

   $('.accordion').on('click',function(){
       $.each(accs,function(acc){
           acc.removeClass('active'); # NOT WORKING
           acc.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show'); # NOT WORKING
       });

       this.classList.toggle('active'); # WORKING
       this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show"); # WORKING

   })
});
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: `acc.removeClass` -> `$(acc).removeClass`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Isn't `acc` the index of the object within the foreach function in the way that he uses it? It should be `accs.eq(acc)...`

Comment: Even in the `$.each()`, function, the first parameter is the key or index value. He only has one argument to his function. See the first example on that page or check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s748hqfy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope below code will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var accs = $('.accordion');

   $('.accordion').on('click',function(){
       accs.each(function(index){
           $(this).removeClass('active');
           $(this).next().removeClass("show");
       });

       $(this).toggleClass('active');
       $(this).next().toggleClass("show");

   })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

wrap `acc` into `$(acc)` - it's just not a jquery object there.

Comment: from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_nextsibling - If you add whitespace between the two li elements, the result will be "undefined".

Comment: This will not work the way hes using it! It will just show up as $(0), $(1). `acc` is not an object **anywhere**.

Answer (score 3):

`removeClass()` is not a native DOM element method, thus you are getting the error. Convert the DOM element into jQuery object then you can use the methods.

Since you already have jQuery object directly use it like

```
 accs.removeClass('active'); //remove class from element
 accs.next().removeClass('show'); //Remove class from sibling
```

instead of

```
   $.each(accs,function(acc){
       acc.removeClass('active'); # NOT WORKING  
       acc.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show'); # NOT WORKING         
   });
```

Comment: What about the `nextSibling` not being found?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Does next statement execute if error is encountered?

Comment: that would make sense. I assumed the OP had tested each line in isolation

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `acc` is the index of the element within the each function. You need to use `$(this).eq(acc)` or `accs.eq(acc).`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var accs = $('.accordion');
    $('.accordion').on('click',function(){
       $.each(accs,function(index){
           accs.eq(index).removeClass("active");
           accs.eq(index).classList.remove("show"); //you don't need next because this each function will remove the class 'active' and 'show' from every accs element regardless
       });

       $(this).toggleClass('active');
       $(this).next().toggleClass("show");
   })
});
```

Right now you're treating an integer (index) as an object. That will not work.